# Cross-validation: splitting data for multi-label regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation, matrix-decomposition

Can you please suggest existing algorithms/implementations/articles for splitting the data for cross-validation for multi-label regression models (matrix factorization and multiple

```
    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  T8
C1  8   6   10  empty   8   8   8   9
C2  9   7   5   9   6   7   10  5
C3  empty   9   9   8   empty   7   10  empty
C4  10  8   5   empty   10  9   empty   10
C5  8   10  empty   5   5   8   10  10
C6  6   6   7   7   5   5       5
C7  6   empty   8   empty   9   empty   6   9
C8  empty   8   6   5   7   10  5   10
C9  8   8   9   8   9   10  10  empty
```

E.g. in sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit the label distribution is treated correctly: labels are accordingly distributed between folds, but the density of label value is not taken into account.
Workaround of course is to convert label values to labels only via binning, e.g. T1:8 to T1_value_4.5, T1_value_5.0, T1_value_5.5, etc. But more elegant solution is needed.